# Baby pinus indentification

Tags: identification, bonsai, pines

I got these baby pine plants from a friend, which I want to nurse for bonsai, however I don't know which species they are. The plants are from seeds, and my friend told me he got the seeds from a cone found near the coast in the dunes (West Netherlands).

I know 3 species of *Pinus* are originally found in the Netherlands, so I think it is one of these three (*Pinus nigra*, *P. sylvestris*, and *P. pinaster*). Does anyone know how to see the difference between the species with baby plants? Does anyone know which species these pines are?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Identification would have been easier if you had kept (or photographed) the cone. But, given the circumstances, I would say it is pinus sylvestris. The other two species are native to mediterranean areas whereas pinus sylvestris is native to your region.

P. sylvestris is an excellent species for bonsai, btw.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately my friend didn't save the cone (I think the seedlings are already 2-3 years old). Nice, I hope the bonsai will work out with these plants!

Comment: Think about wrapping some wire around the trunk and bending it into an interesting shape (known as giving the trunk some movement). It will not be possible after a few more years.